# ios background app is slow to respond from MPNowPlayingInfoCenter

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I created a music app that is wired up to MPNowPlayingInfoCenter. I have a bunch of methods that do various things (next, pause, etc). However, when I hit the next button in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter, the app responds immediately and calls the method instantly when the app is active. However, when the app is playing the background and I hit next from MPNowPlayingInfoCenter, it responds but after a few seconds.

Has anyone else experienced this or have any idea what the culprit might be here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use any graphics code from the background - iOS will kill your app if you do so too much as it takes away from the resources available to foreground apps. It'll also cripple your other background routines.